# multiplication game loop slide issue

Tags: c++, math, testing, while-loop, conditional-statements

So I am determined to make an epic math console based game for fun.

I am curious as to why when the random enters a zero, the program slides through a series of multiplied by 0 and skips the "please enter: " portion of my code.. Is this because of the true and false boolean features of the test condition in the while loop? More importantly how can I stop this from happening?

Thank you for all of your help!

[image]

```
// multiplicationgame.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void game();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    // waiting.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//


    cout << "Welcome to Math game!\n\n" << endl;
    float secs;
    secs = 3;
    clock_t delay = secs * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;              
    clock_t start = clock();
    while (clock() - start < delay )
        ;
    char choice = 'z';
    game();
    while(choice != 'n')
    {

    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 'y')
    {
        cout << "\n\n";
        game();
    }
    else
        choice = 'n';

    }


    return 0;
}

void game()
{

    float secs;
    secs = 33;
    clock_t delay = secs * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;              
    clock_t start = clock();
    int correct = 0;                                    

while (clock() - start < delay )
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a = rand() % 23;
    int b = rand() % 23;
    int c = (a * b);
    int d = 0;
    char choice = 0;

    cout <<"What does " << a << " * " << b << " equal?" << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    while(d != c)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        cin >> d;       
        if(d == c)
             ++correct;
    }
    cout << "\n\nCorrect! " << (a * b) << " is the answer!" << endl << endl;    
}
    cout << "Your score is: " << correct << "\n\n" <<endl;
cout << "Would you like to play again (Y) or (N)?\n\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes, if `c == d == 0`, you do not execute the statements in your while loop. You could initialize d to `-1` to avoid this, or you could switch to a `do while` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Why does it cycle through and eventually stop though? Is this something to do with the call to srand(time(NULL))?

Comment: Initializing `d` to negative one -- or any negative -- value will work because `rand` always returns a non-negative value. However, that is not directly obvious from a casual reading of the code. A comment would make the dependency on the implementation of `rand` clear, but a  do-while loop is a more direct and clearer expression of the logic in this case. Perhaps just "style," but control-flow logic is usually less brittle than "magic" numbers...

Comment: @AEGIS No, the `srand(time(NULL))` merely seeds the random number generator with a somewhat random value based on the current time whenever the program is run. This ensures that each run of the program will produce a different set of multiplication problems to solve.

Comment: @AEGIS The outer `while (clock() - start < delay ) { ... }` loop terminates when the "delay" time has expired. The inner `while(d != c) { ... }` loop is never entered at all when `a` or `b` are zero, or loops forever as long as the user enters wrong answers. So though it is not a real problem in practice -- any user is likely to finally get the correct answer or abort the program manually -- this is a program which is not certain to ever terminate.

Comment: Also, within the inner `while(d != c) { ... }` loop, `if(d == c) ++correct` counts the number of correct answers, but `++correct` can be moved to after the end of the loop and the `if (d == c)` can be deleted because both the loop termination condition and the condition for counting a correct answer are the same and logically redundant.

Comment: A debugger run would have shown the problem to you right away. To avoid waiting for a random 0 value you can use the debugger to change the value to 0 to reproduce the problem.

Comment: As far as why you get 0 multiple times, you go through the loop fast enough that time(NULL) returns the same value, and you are reseeding to the same value.  Thus, with the same seed, rand() will always return the same value.  Eventually time(NULL) gets a one bigger value, and you end up with a new seed.  You should only call srand once (not in a while loop).

Answer (score 0):

You assume the answer is wrong if `c` is not equal to `d`, but if `a` or `b` are set to zero , `c` and `d` are equal before your user can ever enter a number. One solution would be to use a `do { ... } while ( ... );` loop instead of a `while` loop to ensure the user is always asked for a number before your test for the correct answer is performed.

Answer (score 0):

As Markku said, don't set d = 0, because if either a or b is equal 0, then c = a * b = 0 and then your while loop condition c != d won't hold and so it will be skipped

Answer (score 0):

You initialize d to be 0, and anything times 0 is 0.  Thus the (d != c) condition will always be false, and you don't enter the while(d!=c) loop.

You are getting 0 several times, because the while loop finishes very quickly, and so when you call srand(time(NULL)), time(NULL) will return the same value as the previous itteration, and you get the same random seed (which gets you 0 again).

initialize d to be -1 (or some other value that a*b can't be).  Move the srand outside of your while loop -- you only have to (and only should) call srand once in your program.

John

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix:** initialize `int d = -1;` instead of `int d = 0;`.

You're initializing `int c = a * b`. Since either `a` or `b` is zero, the multiplication results in `c` being zero. You also initialize `int d = 0;`. Then you have `while(d != c)`, but you assigned both of them to zero, hence your program skips over that loop because `d != c` is false.

Answer (score 0):

> @AEGIS No, the srand(time(NULL)) merely seeds the random number generator with a somewhat random value based on the current time whenever the program is run. This ensures that each run of the program will produce a different set of multiplication problems to solve.
>
> @AEGIS The outer while (clock() - start < delay ) { ... } loop terminates when the "delay" time has expired. The inner while(d != c) { ... } loop is never entered at all when a or b are zero, or loops forever as long as the user enters wrong answers. So though it is not a real problem in practice -- any user is likely to finally get the correct answer or abort the program manually -- this is a program which is not certain to ever terminate.

@Ned Nowonty looking at the screen shot AEGIS provided the outer loop didn't terminate.  If it did then the

> Your score is: (some number)
>
> Would you like to play again (Y) or (N)?

would have appeared.  When you srand with the same initializer you end up with the same pseudo random numbers.  So when one of the variables was initialized to 0 it would loop around until time(NULL) provided srand a different variable.  In order to avoid that you could use an iterator as well as the time function so the seed would be different all the time.